# moving x number of files into other directories

Tags: bash, shell

I found this bash script that works great

```
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -241)
do
mv $file ../01
done
```

My bash foo is weak, basically if I run inside a directory will move the last 241 files into the folder of /01

The issue is that script itself has to be in the directory with all the files and my current mount has no execute permission. What I would like to do is execute this script from somewhere outside folder for example my working directory /home/user/

my current root directory is on a different drive/partition than where all the files I want to script to act on.

```
for file in **/media/storage1/allfiles** $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -241)
do
mv $file ../01  <this should remain local to /media/storage/
done
```

** EDIT **
I got this to work by adding this before the loop
`cd the/directory/I/want/to/be/in`:

For example

```
cd /media/storage1/allfiles  
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -241)
do
    mv $file ../01
done
```

Better question is: is this the right way to do it, or is there a right way?

Comment: Using `ls` output in a `for` loop is not advisable -- it will break if your files have special characters like white space or `*`.  Otherwise, your logic sounds reasonable.

Comment: It's a perfectly sensible way to do it, though you should think about using a command line parameter for the source directory name and the target directory name (and the number of files to move)— unless everything is really fixed.  All else apart, testing will be easier if you don't have to risk messing up the production directories because you can specify the names on the command line.  Subject to no blanks or other horror stories in the file names (tabs, newlines)…  Also, GNU `mv` has an option `-t directory` which you could use to reduce the number of times you invoke `mv`.

Comment: Something like `mv f1 f2 f2 ../01` would work fine. The benefit of the `-t` option is when using `mv` with something like `find -exec mv -t dir {} +`, where the list of files must come last.

Comment: @codeforester not sure what you mean, so if my file is filename*something.csv I can't list it?  I should be able to list a file that has a space in the name no? good point though I'll make considerations for odd characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, I would do the following to avoid using `ls`. It takes advantage of the fact that you weren't trying to sort the files in any particular fashion, so whatever order is provided by the pathname expansion will be sufficient.

```
cd /media/storage1/allfiles
# Get *all* regular files in the target directory
for f in *; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && files+=("$f")
done
# Get the file count
n=${#files[@]}
# How many files are we *not* moving
# Assume n > 241
keep=$((n - 241 ))
# Move the last 241 files
mv -- "${files[@]:keep}" ../01
```

Presumably, 241 files will not be so long as to overflow the command line.

---

Unsolicited `zsh` plug...

`zsh` makes this a bit easier, as you can make the shell do a lot of the selection work with the glob itself.

```
mv /media/storage/allfiles/*(.On[1,241]) ../01
```

The `(...)` following the glob is a set of glob qualifiers that restrict the list of files produces. `.` indicates only regular files should be matched. `On` sorts the list in reverse order by name (other sort orders can be used by replacing `n` with an appropriate charater). `[1,241]` restricts the list to the first 241 files; since we sorted in reverse order, this gives you the last 241 files.

Comment: ah just  little background @chepner 241 is because I had many files and running my script against them only used 1 core per instance run. So I spit the files in to 20 (I have 24 cores) and then ran the program 20 times concurrently to max out the cores. . Your script is nice, just curious why avoid using ls?

Comment: Technically, `ls` does not write one file per line; it writes filenames separated by newlines, and filenames *can* (no matter how rarely they *do*) contain newlines. That means you cannot assume that a line of text is a complete file name.